# Tikz: convert an object to a filled path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

Let's say I have such a simple tikz "contour" object defined with `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

\def\object{
    \draw[blue, thick, -stealth] (0,  0)
                     .. controls (5, -5)
                             and (10, 5)
                              .. (15, 0);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \object
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way I could convert it to an actual `\fill`ed path? Drawing it is easy with `\draw`, but transforming it (in particular, [*fading*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/) it) would be more easy if it were drawn with `\fill`.. but what a pain would it be to design it with `\fill`!

I am aware that the problem is that, since it is declared as a path, it has no `width` in theory. The thing is that it *does* have a width orelse we could not see it. The question is: how to take this actual width into account and turn it into an explicit path?

Put it another way: how would you draw a black outline around this object?

(Yes, I am thinking about Inkscape's `object to path` or [`convert to path`](https://inkscape.org/fr/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html) feature.)

---

**[EDIT]** If my understanding of [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17950/) is correct, I would need to highjack the code from `stealth` in a heavy `\makeatletter .. \makeatother` section so that I could retrieve the actual contour of the whole arrow.

However, I am actually using `Stealth` from `arrows.meta`, and I would not like the code to be rewritten if I fancy change `Stealth` to `Latex`. What I am looking for is a more generic solution to retrieve the actual path primitive built when I type: `\draw[blue, thick, -stealth] (0, 0) .. controls (5, -5) and (10, 5) .. (15, 0);` It *must* be computed at some point internally otherwise the compilation would be meaningless. How can I get this intermediate result?

---

In an ideal world, I would type:

`\getActualPath{\object}{\result}`

and `\result` would then be magically expanded as:

```
\path[cm={{0.8,0.0,0.0,-0.8,(-0.398,5.38)}}]
    (17.3457,1.2305) -- (16.9707,3.8555) .. controls (16.4721,3.4476) and
    (15.9195,3.2113) .. (15.3516,3.1621) .. controls (14.6806,3.1040) and
    (14.0125,3.2715) .. (13.3496,3.5488) .. controls (12.0238,4.1035) and
    (10.6766,5.1107) .. (9.2793,6.0215) .. controls (7.8820,6.9323) and
    (6.4476,7.7369) .. (5.0586,7.9473) .. controls (3.6696,8.1576) and
    (2.3182,7.8417) .. (0.8496,6.3730) -- (0.1465,7.0762) .. controls
    (1.7912,8.7209) and (3.5542,9.1820) .. (5.2070,8.9316) .. controls
    (6.8598,8.6813) and (8.3943,7.7895) .. (9.8242,6.8574) .. controls
    (11.2541,5.9253) and (12.5908,4.9452) .. (13.7344,4.4668) .. controls
    (14.3062,4.2276) and (14.8182,4.1155) .. (15.2656,4.1543) .. controls
    (15.6068,4.1839) and (15.9194,4.2931) .. (16.2363,4.5293) --
    (13.6836,4.8926) -- (19.1777,6.7246) -- (17.3457,1.2305) -- cycle
```

so that

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \result[draw, fill=blue, line width=.1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would draw

[image]

and, with `\usetikzlibrary{fadings}`,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \result[path fading=west, fill=blue];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would draw

[image]

and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \result[clip];
    \node () at (8, 5) {\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would draw

[image]

.. would this not be neat?

Comment: `\newcommand\object[1][draw]{\path[blue, thick, -stealth, #1]
        (0, 0) .. controls (5, -5) and (10, 5) .. (15, 0);}` and then `\object[fill]`?

Comment: Or `\def\object{[blue, thick, -stealth] (0, 0) .. controls (5, -5) and (10, 5) .. (15, 0);}` and then `\draw\object` and `\fill\object`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, and it does exactly what *I* expect.  I don't know what *you* expect though, since your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I draw the outline of a path in tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17950/how-can-i-draw-the-outline-of-a-path-in-tikz)

Comment: @HenriMenke For example, I may wish to 1) `draw` a black outline all around the blue arrow, like you would do with a pencil.. or 2) `clip` a random picture so that it would be shaped like this arrow.. or 3) `shade` this arrow to that it would fade away going west.. For all these purposes, I would need the actual contour object to be a `path`, not just `(0, 0) .. controls (5, -5) and (10, 5) .. (15, 0)`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Possibly indeed. I'll get into this :)

Comment: As I understand it from LoopSpace's answer, this is simply not possible for arrow heads. Unless the introduction of `arrows.meta` has changed things? But that answer suggests it can be done for paths. I don't think this is a duplicate now it has been edited. It may well not be possible, though. That is, there may well be no solution which works as easily as you hope.

Comment: @cfr too bad.. well, this is only 2016, right ? ;) What would you think of as a workaround then?

Comment: It's your question ;). And I don't know what difference `arrows.meta` makes.

Comment: You can fade it as a path, but I guess you know that?

Answer (score 2):

For fading, there really isn't a problem as we can fade a path or use a `scope fading` to apply whatever fading effects we wish to any path, even if the path is merely drawn rather than filled. We can apply this equally to paths specified and drawn within the scope and to predefined paths such as `\object`. For example

\begin{scope}[opacity=1,transparency group]
        \path [scope fading=west] (0,-2) rectangle (3,1);
        \object
        \draw [green, ultra thick, -{Stealth[bend]}] (0,1) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);
      \end{scope}

There is one caveat to this which is that the method works fine when the arrows are heading in the direction of opacity, but less well when the arrows head for transparency. That is, if we add

```
    \draw [magenta, ultra thick, {Stealth[bend]}-] (0,-1) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,-1);
```

to our scope, the results will be less satisfactory. How much of an issue this is depends on the amount of transparency, type of arrow tip and size of arrow tip.

For greater flexibility, you can define `\object` to take an optional argument allowing you to write, for example,

```
\object[path fading=east]
```

or whatever.

This also permits a rather fiddly and not entirely satisfactory workaround for the outlining issue because we can say, for example

```
    \object[double=blue, draw=black, line width=.4pt, double distance=1.2pt, -{Stealth[sep=-9.5pt,fill=blue,width=1.7ex,length=2.1ex,bend]}]
```

to approximate an outlined version of our arrow. This can be additionally faded if placed within the scope we defined above. However, the solution is fiddly and the outline of the arrow tip is drawn completely which we would prefer not to happen.

The results look as follows:

[image: tweaking arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,arrows.meta,fadings}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\object[1][]{%
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, -{Stealth[bend]}, #1] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,0);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[opacity=1,transparency group]
    \path [scope fading=west] (0,-2) rectangle (3,1);
    \scoped[yshift=-15mm]{\object[double=blue, draw=black, line width=.4pt, double distance=1.2pt, -{Stealth[sep=-9.5pt,fill=blue,width=1.7ex,length=2.1ex,bend]}]}
    \object
    \draw [green, ultra thick, -{Stealth[bend]}] (0,1) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,1);
    \draw [magenta, ultra thick, {Stealth[bend]}-] (0,-1) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,1) .. (3,-1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a quite simple workaround for the first two use cases, thanks :) I cannot mark the answer as accepted, but why not gathering here other neat workarounds? I have just added another use case for my utopic `\getActualPath` command.

Comment: Interestingly, the fading is not visible with Evince, which is the reason why I could not get `scope fading` working when I first tried it.. [crab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab#/media/File:Liocarcinus_vernalis.jpg)!

Comment: Strange. The screenshots are from Okular and I thought both were poppler based.

Comment: I thought so as well. I migrated towards Okular just to get your example working.. and the rendering is now awful even though fading is supported.. compiling the latest version of `poppler` had no magic effect. Any idea how to tell Okular which renderer to use?

Comment: Not really. Mine just works. (Or I'm less particular about rendering.) I imagine it is a question of what Okular is compiled with rather than anything else. I have version 15.12.3 of Okular with 0.41.0 of the Poppler-QT4 bindings and 0.41.0 of Poppler. (Arch is mostly using QT5 stuff, but some things still need QT4.)